# how many bytes should I read from files stored locally for hash check

Tags: python

```
    def get_chunks(self):
        fd = open(self.path, 'rb')
        while True:
            chunk = fd.read(1)
            if not chunk:
                break

            yield chunk
        fd.close()

    def calculate(self):
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
        sha512 = hashlib.sha512()

        for chunk in self.get_chunks():
            md5.update(chunk)
            sha256.update(chunk)
            sha512.update(chunk)

        self.md5 = md5.hexdigest()
        self.sha256 = sha256.hexdigest()
        self.sha512 = sha512.hexdigest()
```

I am using multiple hash algorithms to try to identify files on my computer, I have encountered a problem while making this tool in python, the problem is:
"How many bytes should I read at one time if I intend to use them to update multiple hash algorithms and still keep the idea for this piece of code to run correctly on as many platforms as possible?"

any suggestions please?

Comment: With your current approach, you identify each piece of bytes instead of the whole file. Is this intended?

Comment: i think that is not how the update function is designed for，actually the algorithm itself should be designed with the capability of handling large file in mind

Answer (score 0):

I would go for one hash algorithm to hash each complete files. And in order to avoid a collision problems compare the colliding files completely bytewise. This should put you in a safe spot.

Comment: i just cant upload all these files for security check，i use this method to detect a possible fake download source due to bad Internet management.